# Docker Desktop errors out running on Windows 10 pro v1903

Tags: virtualization, docker, hyper-v, disk-image, hypervisor

It said I need to enable virtualization,
which means running Hyper-V, 
so I followed this guide:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/enable-hyper-v

But when I try to run the instance in Hyper-V Manager, it says "Hypervisor isn't running"

Answer (score 0):

The order in which you enable Windows features matters.

Type in "features" into Windows search and select "Turn Windows features on or off" to enter the Windows Features applet.

Go to Windows Features and uncheck the following:

- Windows Hypervisor Platform
- Virtual Machine Platform
- Hyper-V

Click OK and reboot.

Then recheck them one by one:

- Windows Hypervisor Platform -> OK
- Virtual Machine Platform -> OK
- Hyper-V -> OK

[Windows Features](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGjQF.png)

After that Docker Desktop should be able to run smoothly on autostart